# Cómo ejecutar un spinner cuando la página esté cargando? $("#loader").slideDown();

Tags: javascript, java, html, jquery, spinner

Estimada comunidad, deseo ejecutar un spinner (cargando) con un código `JS` dentro de un `HTML` al momento de presionar un botón.

La idea es simple, que muestre un spinner cargando mientras la página está cargando pero no logro llegar a aquello.

Dejo un poco de código.

```html
<button onclick="dirigir()" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Descargar Tabla</button>
<script>
  function dirigir() {
    window.onload(function() {
      $("#loader").slideDown();
    });
  };
</script>
```

Ese script está dentro del `HTML`, la idea es que al presionar el botón con el `onClick="dirigir()"` ejecute ese trozo de código, la función `window.onload`.

Por lo que estuve investigando ejecuta un código mientras se está cargando la página, y es ahí dentro en donde agrego el spinner `$("#loader").slideDown();` pero no funciona.

Espero puedan ayudarme, muchas gracias comunidad!!!

Comment: Prueba quitando el `window.onload` -> `function dirigir() { $("#loader").slideDown(); }`

Comment: @Cris223511.dev si también lo hice así y muestra el spinner pero todo el rato, aún cuando deja de cargar la página, es por eso que le he agregado el window.onload, y hay una corrección, es window.onload = function....

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que entiendo, buscas mostrar un spinner al hacer click en el botón y que se oculte una vez cargados los datos de la tabla.

Para ello creé un spinner básico con `CSS`. Este spinner debe estar oculto por defecto. Y con `setTimeout` estoy simulando la finalización de la carga.

```css
#loader {
  border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
  border-top: 16px solid #3498db;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  display: none; /* El spinner debe estar oculto por defecto */
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="dirigir()" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Descargar Tabla</button>
<br><br>
<div id="loader"></div>
<div id="tabla"></div>
<script>
  function dirigir() {
    //Al hacer click en el botón se muestra el spinner
    $("#loader").show("slow");
    //En cinco segundos se oculta el spinner y se muestra la tabla
    setTimeout(() => {
      $("#loader").hide("slow");
      $("#tabla").html('<table border="1"><tr><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr></table>');
    }, "5000");
  };
</script>
```

Deja un comentario o agrega más detalles a la pregunta si no es lo que buscas.